# Java Map compute() Example on Java 1.6

Tags: java, java-6

I have to work on Java 1.6. I have difficulty converting the following code running on Java 1.8.

```
Map<String, Double> maksimum = new HashMap<>();
List<Record> records;
for (Record record : records) {
    record.getFeatures().forEach((key, value) -> {
        maksimum.compute(key, (k1, max) -> max == null || value > max ? value : max);
    });
}
```

what I have transformed is as follows. I wonder where I'm doing wrong.

```
for(Record rec : records) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : rec.getFeatures().entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey()==null || maksimum.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            maksimum.replace(entry.getKey(), maksimum.get(entry.getValue()));
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full Java 8 code (with proper indentation). Otherwise it's hard to know what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Hello, it was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your initial code in Java 8, you want to store the maximum value for every key in your `Map`. Here is the code that should do that in Java 6:

```
Map<String, Double> maksimum = new HashMap<String, Double>();

for (Record record : records) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> recordEntry : record.getFeatures().entrySet()) {
        String key = recordEntry.getKey();
        Double value = recordEntry.getValue();

        Double initialValue = maksimum.get(key);
        if (initialValue == null) {
            maksimum.put(key, value);
        } else {
            maksimum.put(key, Math.max(value, initialValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `replace` function that you've used in your example was introduced in Java 8. Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replace-K-V-

Comment: hello I want to translate this project.
, https://www.baeldung.com/java-k-means-clustering-algorithm